# IS it possible to have a Scenario table without any actor request?

Tags: uml, software-design

I have a general feature for sending user location to the server, finding location of him on the map and then finding some places near him.
If I separate this feature to two use cases, Second scenario table should start with no acting from member actor.
My question is if I can use two use cases and write second scenario table without acting from actor or should I combine two in one use case and scenario table

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn that UCs are not meant to be decomposed. A UC represents a single added value for an actor dealing with the system under consideration. If there is no actor involved, you don't have a UC.

If you encounter lots of scenarios which are repeated in different UCs, then most likely your system is cut the wrong way.